# R Create objects in loop named depending on i

Tags: r, loops

I have nearly the same problem as [for loop to output different objects in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843946/for-loop-to-output-different-objects-in-r) but I don't get it even considering the solution here (Sorry):
I want to create objects (can be matrix, vector or else) depending on calender years.

I create the actual year as number:

```
now<-Sys.time()
actualyear<-strftime(now, format="%Y")
actualyear<-as.numeric(actualyear)
class(actualyear)
```

In this case I want to create 7 objects named test2011, test2012, test2013, .... test2017 with the equivilant calender year as content (test2011 <- 2011, test2012 <- 2012, ....)

```
for(i in 2011:actualyear) {test[[i]]<-i}
```

Comment: Create a list with elements (which can be named). My advice would be to avoid using `assign` and cluttering your workspace with objects. Lists are perfect to avoid this kind of coding practice.

Comment: you can add after your code `names(test)=paste("test",2011:actualyear)`

Comment: It will be great to use `paste0` instead of `paste`. The `paste` functions without collapsing the arguments creates names with spaces in between them. These names are not recommended in programming. thus better use : `names(test)=paste0("test",2011:actualyear)`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, you can assign a value to a name with `assign`

```
for(i in 2011:actualyear) {
  assign(paste0("test", i), i)
}
```