# Using a for loop in combination with a formula (mice) to create multiple objects (outcomes) of the formula

Tags: r, object, for-loop, r-mice

I am using `mice` to impute my data. It has a neat feature which creates a prediction matrix for your dataframe based on the correlation between variables.

[LINK](https://www.gerkovink.com/miceVignettes/Convergence_pooling/Convergence_and_pooling.html)

Because I have multiple datasets that need imputing and it takes quite a long time, I want to create the prediction matrix for each `df` in `ls()` with a `for` loop. The vignette example is as follows:

```
require(mice)
require(lattice)
set.seed(123)

ini <- mice(nhanes, pred=quickpred(nhanes, mincor=.3), print=F)
ini$pred
##     age bmi hyp chl
## age   0   0   0   0
## bmi   1   0   0   1
## hyp   1   0   0   1
## chl   1   1   1   0
```

I would like to do something like:

```
for (i in ls())  {
  pred[[i]]=quickpred(ls(i), mincor=.3)
}
```

However, I cannot get the syntax right. The idea would be that it creates an instance of `pred` for every item in `ls()`. I have looked at the links below, but I cannot seem to get it right:

[1. R Create objects in loop named..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843946/for-loop-to-output-different-objects-in-r)

[2. for loop to output different objects..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45454340/r-create-objects-in-loop-named-depending-on-i)

EDIT: With some help I have been able to advance my answer to the following;

```
pred = list()
for (i in 1:length(ls()))  {
pred[[i]]=quickpred(get(ls()[i]), mincor=.3)
}
```

I have not had time to thoroughly test, but got no error yet.

Comment: can you share please your error message @Tom?
I have several assumptions:
1. list pred is not initialised
2. you can write instead of ls(i) just i
3. the object you address by i is not a data.frame

Comment: So my last edit actually worked. It creates a list of matrices.